# Manage more iframes' history from the parent window

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Is it possible to navigate through the single iframes' history via back buttons placed in the  main page that contains many iframes?
So, when i press BACK button #1, i go back ONLY in iframe #1, BACK #2 has effect only on iframe #2, ...
Or is there only one history object that "shows" simultaneously the content of the iframes?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I've tried with this function:  document.getElementById('iframe_name').contentWindow.history.back(); but if i press button #1, for example, i see changing the content of the iframe #3 (for example) because it is the last used for navigating.